CMon enriched categories
Let CMon denote the symmetric monoidal category of commutative monoids, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal category enriched over CMon. According to this n-lab page, the following holds.
Let $0_{X,Y}$ denote the identity in $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$. For all $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and $Z \in \mathcal{C}$, we have $f \circ 0_{Z,X} = 0_{Z,Y}$ and $0_{Y,Z} \circ f = 0_{X,Z}$.
For some reason, I’m really struggling to see why that follows from the definition. Does anyone have a reference or see a simple proof?

Composition is a bihomomorphism (or biadditive or bilinear, if you prefer those words) by definition. Therefore it preserves the identity (or zero) in both arguments.

This is a complete answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@ZhenLin, if you copy/paste this as an answer, I will accept it.

I have a hard time figuring out what level of detail is needed for questions like this. Frankly, I think what I wrote was barely a step more helpful than “reread the definition carefully”.

Composition is a bihomomorphism (or biadditive or bilinear, if you prefer those words) by definition. Therefore it preserves the identity (or zero) in both arguments.
